# python - Reading a .csv with multiple languages in column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, mojibake

I am trying to explore the recently posted Russion investigation tweets database. First of 9 csv files here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/master/IRAhandle_tweets_1.csv

The dataset has a column "content" with the tweet content. Tweets are in more than 50 languages.

Any way to read the .csv with such an encoding that at least Latin + Cyrillic tweets are displayed properly in the same dataset?

I tried pd.read_csv with UTF-8 and cp1251, but no success so far. Latin tweets are displayed properly, Cyrillic - not.

For example, line 372 in the file, read as binary, has the following value:

```
(b'2528776985,1488REASONS,"\xc3\x90\xc2\x9f\xc3\x91\xc2\x80\xc3\x90\xc2\xb8'
 b'\xc3\x91\xc2\x87\xc3\x90\xc2\xb8\xc3\x90\xc2\xbd\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0 #67'
 b' \xc3\x90\xc2\x9c\xc3\x91\xc2\x83\xc3\x91\xc2\x82\xc3\x90\xc2'
 b'\xba\xc3\x90\xc2\xbe: \xc3\x82\xc2\xab\xc3\x90\xc2\x97\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3'
 b'\x90\xc2\xbd\xc3\x90\xc2\xb8\xc3\x91\xc2\x82-\xc3\x90\xc2\x90'
 b'\xc3\x91\xc2\x80\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xbd\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5'
 b'\xc3\x82\xc2\xbb \xc3\x90\xc2\xb4\xc3\x90\xc2\xbb\xc3\x91\xc2\x8f \xc3\x90'
 b'\xc2\xb0\xc3\x90\xc2\xb4\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0\xc3\x90\xc2\xbf\xc3\x91'
 b'\xc2\x82\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0\xc3\x91\xc2\x86\xc3\x90\xc2\xb8\xc3\x90'
 b'\xc2\xb8 \xc3\x90\xc2\xba \xc3\x90\xc2\xa7\xc3\x90\xc2\x9c \xc3\x90\xc2'
 b'\xbf\xc3\x90\xc2\xbe\xc3\x91\xc2\x82\xc3\x91\xc2\x80\xc3\x90\xc2'
 b'\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xb1\xc3\x91\xc2\x83\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3\x91\xc2'
 b'\x82\xc3\x91\xc2\x81\xc3\x91\xc2\x8f 1,5\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x932'
 b' \xc3\x90\xc2\xbc\xc3\x90\xc2\xbb\xc3\x91\xc2\x80\xc3\x90\xc2\xb4 \xc3\x91'
 b'\xc2\x80\xc3\x91\xc2\x83\xc3\x90\xc2\xb1\xc3\x90\xc2\xbb\xc3\x90'
 b'\xc2\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xb9",Unknown,Russian,1/19/2017 13:07,1/19/2017 13:07,'
 b'6311,6313,1806,,Russian,0,0,NonEnglish\r\n')
```

so when decoding as UTF-8 the `content` value becomes:

```
('Ð\x9fÑ\x80Ð¸Ñ\x87Ð¸Ð½Ð° #67 Ð\x9cÑ\x83Ñ\x82ÐºÐ¾: '
 'Â«Ð\x97ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ\x82-Ð\x90Ñ\x80ÐµÐ½ÐµÂ» Ð´Ð»Ñ\x8f Ð°Ð´Ð°Ð¿Ñ\x82Ð°Ñ\x86Ð¸Ð¸ Ðº '
 'Ð§Ð\x9c Ð¿Ð¾Ñ\x82Ñ\x80ÐµÐ±Ñ\x83ÐµÑ\x82Ñ\x81Ñ\x8f 1,5â\x80\x932 Ð¼Ð»Ñ\x80Ð´ '
 'Ñ\x80Ñ\x83Ð±Ð»ÐµÐ¹')
```

which prints as

```
ÐÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð½Ð° #67 ÐÑÑÐºÐ¾: Â«ÐÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ-ÐÑÐµÐ½ÐµÂ» Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð°Ð´Ð°Ð¿ÑÐ°ÑÐ¸Ð¸ Ðº Ð§Ð Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑÐµÐ±ÑÐµÑÑÑ 1,5â2 Ð¼Ð»ÑÐ´ ÑÑÐ±Ð»ÐµÐ¹
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: Thanks @Martjin and please excuse the lack of initial example. I use pd.read_csv(link, encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: I added that data by opening the file in binary mode, then looping over it to find the matching binary data for good examples found in the dataframe from the same source, then using `pprint.pprint()` to nicely format the raw data.

Comment: Heads-up: the repository encoding has been fixed now, see the [issue I filed](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/issues/5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** the dataset [has now been fixed](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/commit/d944a52dc93135d51f283bbdbd02e02f3911b28d) and no longer needs conversion. The answer below no longer need apply.

---

The dataset contains [Mojibake data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), data that has been encoded *twice*. First to UTF-8, then treated as bytes to then be encoded to UTF-8 *again*.

You could fix this by encoding Latin-1 first to map the UTF-8 codepoints in the Unicode text back to bytes, then decoding as UTF-8 again:

```
content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Demo:

```
>>> content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Причина #67 Мутко: «Зенит-Арене» для адаптации к ЧМ потребуется 1,5–2 млрд рублей'
>>> print(content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
Причина #67 Мутко: «Зенит-Арене» для адаптации к ЧМ потребуется 1,5–2 млрд рублей
```

You can apply this transformation to the whole column in a Pandas dataframe:

```
df.content = df.content.str.encode('latin1').str.decode('utf8')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/master/IRAhandle_tweets_1.csv', encoding='utf8')
>>> df.iloc[372].content
'Ð\x9fÑ\x80Ð¸Ñ\x87Ð¸Ð½Ð° #67 Ð\x9cÑ\x83Ñ\x82ÐºÐ¾: Â«Ð\x97ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ\x82-Ð\x90Ñ\x80ÐµÐ½ÐµÂ» Ð´Ð»Ñ\x8f Ð°Ð´Ð°Ð¿Ñ\x82Ð°Ñ\x86Ð¸Ð¸ Ðº Ð§Ð\x9c Ð¿Ð¾Ñ\x82Ñ\x80ÐµÐ±Ñ\x83ÐµÑ\x82Ñ\x81Ñ\x8f 1,5â\x80\x932 Ð¼Ð»Ñ\x80Ð´ Ñ\x80Ñ\x83Ð±Ð»ÐµÐ¹'
>>> df.content = df.content.str.encode('latin1').str.decode('utf8')
>>> df.iloc[372].content
'Причина #67 Мутко: «Зенит-Арене» для адаптации к ЧМ потребуется 1,5–2 млрд рублей'
```

I've [filed an issue with the project](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/issues/5) to have the encoding fixed.

Comment: Thanks a million! Tested, worked great. Please excuse the lack of initial example - my first question here, I will know better.